# My iPad is being held for ransom

Tags: malware

I was able to restore my *iPhone* and *iPod* but my *iPad* is "offline" preventing me from getting out of lost mode.  I also have a call in to Apple.

I've changed my Apple ID password and had to cancel my credit cards.

Any help out there?

Comment: How is it being held for ransom?

Comment: someone hacked into my apple acct and put it on "lost mode" and changed the passcode.  On the front of the screen, written in Russian is basically "if you want your device back, you have to send us money"

Comment: On the iPad screen or on Safari?

Answer (score 3):

Take the device into an Apple Store and explain the situation to them. Under certain circumstances they may be able to fix such an issue (for example, they are able to remove an iCloud lock from a MacBook, but it takes several days and several checks are done to ensure you own the device)